# Adjust contrast or color for display

Tags: display, configuration

I am using Ubuntu 22.04 and Gnome 42 on an old MacBook Pro 2011 (pre-Retina). I really need to adjust the contrast, or white balance.
I have tried using xgamma, xrandr, redshift and changing different color profiles but nothing helps..
Anyone who can help?

Comment: switch to xorg instead of Wayland? then xrandr and similar will work properly.

Comment: I appreciate the tip, but I don't want to make such drastic changes to my system.. I was just looking for maybe a simple tool or edit to achieve this..

Comment: there probably is none, Wayland is not quite up to it . But it isn't a major change: every time you log in, you can choose to use wayland or xorg. in the bottom-right of the login screen there is a cog icon, click it and choose "Ubuntu on Xorg"

Comment: also, xorg used to be default on Ubuntu in 20.04, and now Wayland is default. Xorg is still installed by default, just not used by default.